# How to make required on Ajax form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i had upload button that using ajax and i want this action is required, this is the code.

button code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('image', 'Image: ', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label required']) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="modalgambar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="tambahgambar"></button>
      <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block"><i></b></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="tambahgambar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
      </div>

      <form id="upload-image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input id="input-dim-1" name="inputdim1[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading" accept="image/*">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ajax:

```
$('#form-product').submit(function(event) {
         if ($("#input-dim-1").val() == '') {
           event.preventDefault();
           alert("Image Is Required");
         } else {
           if(! validationInput()) {
             form.submit();
           }

          alert('Stok tidak boleh minus');  
         }


         return false;

       });
```

the alert("Image Is Required") is appear when im not uploaded picture, but that alert is appear too when i uploaded the picture, so confusing. :(
can someone help me?
i try find anysolution but i didnt found it yet :(

Comment: i don't see nay ajax, what are you talking about?

Comment: @madalinivascu umm sorry im still newbee at this, in the last code, is it ajax or what? sorry before

Comment: alert('Stok tidak boleh minus');  when do you want to show this alertt?

Comment: if u need a image up loader check this demo  http://phppot.com/demo/php-ajax-image-upload/

Comment: @Exprator the alert that always appear is alert("Image Is Required"), this alert appear too when i had uploaded image

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the button code with this :

```
 {!! Form::file('image',Input::old('image'), [ 'class' => 'form-control','required'=>'required']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the form actually gets submitted twice. You are triggering the "form submit" from the "form submit event".

You need to remove the line `form.submit();`